# switch statement only sometimes works

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

The Switch doesn't work at first, but after a few clicks, case 7 does appear.  I used an alert to make the sure the speechNum++ worked, and it did.  I also used an if statement with a === to make sure speechNum remained as a number, and it did that also.  This started after I added the save and cheat functions (though I don't see how).  Only the Javascript could have issues.  I have a theory that I have misplaced a }, but, if so ,I can't find it.  I know the images don't appear, but it doesn't matter.  Thanks in advance!

```js
var gameContainer = document.getElementById("game-container");

var gender;
var name = "";

var speechBox = document.createElement("DIV");
 speechBox.id = "speech-box";
 var speechP = document.createElement("P");
  speechP.id = "speech-p"
  var speech = document.createTextNode("");
 var speechNum = 0;
 var text = true;
function mainMenu() {
   gameContainer.removeChild(document.getElementById("start-button"));      //button disappears
    document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('warning'));                          //warning disappears
 var mainMenuBox = document.createElement("DIV");
  mainMenuBox.id = "main-menu-box";
 var mainMenuBoxNew = document.createElement("P");
  mainMenuBoxNew.className = "main-menu-box-p";
  mainMenuBoxNew.innerHTML = "New Game";
   var mainMenuBoxNewPic = document.createElement("IMG");
    mainMenuBoxNewPic.className = "main-menu-box-pic";
    mainMenuBoxNewPic.src = "index/src/img/menu/red.gif"
    mainMenuBoxNew.appendChild(mainMenuBoxNewPic);
  mainMenuBoxNew.onmouseenter = function(){mainMenuBoxNewPic.src = "index/src/img/menu/redAnimated.gif";}
  mainMenuBoxNew.onmouseleave = function(){mainMenuBoxNewPic.src = "index/src/img/menu/red.gif";}
  mainMenuBoxNew.onclick = function(){gameContainer.removeChild(mainMenuBox);
            preProfessorOpen();
            return;
        }
 var mainMenuBoxSave = document.createElement("P");
  mainMenuBoxSave.className = "main-menu-box-p";
  mainMenuBoxSave.innerHTML = "Save Code";
   var mainMenuBoxSavePic = document.createElement("IMG");
    mainMenuBoxSavePic.className = "main-menu-box-pic";
    mainMenuBoxSavePic.src = "index/src/img/menu/binary.jpg";
    mainMenuBoxSave.appendChild(mainMenuBoxSavePic);
  mainMenuBoxSave.onmouseenter = function(){mainMenuBoxSavePic.src = "index/src/img/menu/binaryAnimated.gif";}
  mainMenuBoxSave.onmouseleave = function(){mainMenuBoxSavePic.src = "index/src/img/menu/binary.jpg";}
        mainMenuBoxSave.onclick = function(){gameContainer.removeChild(mainMenuBox);
            inputSaveCode();
            return;
        }
 var mainMenuBoxCheat = document.createElement("P");
  mainMenuBoxCheat.className = "main-menu-box-p";
  mainMenuBoxCheat.innerHTML = "Cheat Code";
   var mainMenuBoxCheatPic = document.createElement("IMG");
    mainMenuBoxCheatPic.className = "main-menu-box-pic";
    mainMenuBoxCheatPic.src = "index/src/img/menu/cheatCode.jpg";
    mainMenuBoxCheat.appendChild(mainMenuBoxCheatPic);
  mainMenuBoxCheat.onmouseenter = function(){mainMenuBoxCheatPic.src = "index/src/img/menu/cheatCodeAnimated.gif";}
  mainMenuBoxCheat.onmouseleave = function(){mainMenuBoxCheatPic.src = "index/src/img/menu/cheatCode.jpg";}
        mainMenuBoxCheat.onclick = function(){gameContainer.removeChild(mainMenuBox);
            inputCheatCode();
            return;
        }
 gameContainer.appendChild(mainMenuBox);
 mainMenuBox.appendChild(mainMenuBoxNew);
 mainMenuBox.appendChild(mainMenuBoxSave);
 mainMenuBox.appendChild(mainMenuBoxCheat);
}

function preProfessorOpen() {
 document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(index/src/img/yellowDiamond/professor.png)";
 gameContainer.appendChild(speechBox);
  speechBox.appendChild(speechP);
  speechP.innerHTML = "Welcome to the world of Pok&eacute;mon, clod!";
 speechBox.onclick = function(){professorOpen();}
  function professorOpen() {
   speechNum++;
   switch(speechNum) {
    case 1:
     speech = "I am Yellow Diamond &ndash; reduced to introducing Pok&eacute;mon Spin-Offs.";
     break;
    case 2:
     speech = "This world of clods is widely inhabited by creatures known as Pok&eacute;mon.";
     break;
    case 3:
     speech = "These mysterious creature can be found in every corner of this world...";
     break;
    case 4:
     speech = "Some run across the plains, others fly through the skies, and others yet swim deep in the oceans...";
     break;
    case 5:
     speech = "Clods live together with these Pok&eacute;mon, lending their little strength to one another to live and prosper.";
     break;
    case 6:
     speech = "Let's get started with some quick questions...<br>Are you a boy? Or are you a girl?<br>(Probably a boy if Alex shared this with you.)";
     break;
    case 7:
     speechBox.onclick = function(){}
                    speechBox.style.cursor = 'default';
     speechBox.innerHTML = '<p id="male" class="pointer">Boy</p> \
                <p id="female" class="pointer">Girl</p>'
                                           document.getElementById("male").onclick = function(){gender = "boy"; professorOpen(); return;}
                                           document.getElementById("female").onclick = function(){gender = "girl"; professorOpen(); return;}
     break;
    case 8:
     speechBox.innerHTML = "<p id='gender-confirm'>So, you're a " + gender + "?</p> \
       <span id='yes-gender-p' class='pointer'>Yep!</span> \
                            <br> \
       <span id='no-gender-p' class='pointer'>No, obviously.</span>";
        document.getElementById("yes-gender-p").onclick = function(){professorOpen(); return;}
        document.getElementById("no-gender-p").onclick = function(){speechNum = 6; professorOpen(); return;}
                    break;
               case 9:
                    speechBox.onclick = function(){professorOpen();}
                    speechBox.innerHTML = "";
                    speechBox.appendChild(speechP);
                    speechBox.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                    speech = "Also, what is your name?";
                    break;
               case 10:
                    speechBox.onclick = function(){};
                    speechBox.innerHTML = '<label for="name" id="name-lbl">Name</label> \
                        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"> \
                        <input type="submit" id="name-submit" class="pointer" value="Submit">';
                            document.getElementById("name-submit").onclick = function(){name=document.getElementById('name').value; professorOpen(); return;}
                    break;
               case 11:
                    speechBox.innerHTML = "<p id='name-confirm'>So, you're name is " + name + "?</p> \
                       <span id='yes-name-p' class='pointer'>Yep!</span> \
                       <br> \
        <span id='no-name-p' class='pointer'>No, obviously.</span>";
                            document.getElementById("yes-name-p").onclick = function(){professorOpen(); return;}
       document.getElementById("no-name-p").onclick = function(){speechNum = 9; professorOpen(); return;}
                    break;
               case 12:
                    speechBox.onclick = function(){professorOpen();}
                    speechBox.innerHTML = "";
                    speechBox.appendChild(speechP);
                    speechBox.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                    speech = name + ' Tr&eacute;s bien!<br>What a fantastic name!';
                    break;
               case 13:
                    speech = name + '! Your adventure begins now!<br>You are about to scale the beautiful Malachite mountain!';
                    break;
               case 14:
                    speech = 'Go and meet many Pok&eacute;mon, and fill your life with rich experiences!';
                    break;
               case 15:
                    speech = "Now let's go visit the world of Pok&eacute;mon!";
                    break;
               case 16:
                    speech = 'But before you go, remember that on this island.  You cannot catch new Pok&eacute;mon unless you already have room in your party! Good luck!';
                    speechBox.onclick = function(){enterIsland();}
    speechP.innerHTML = speech;
            }
  }           //professOpen Func End
}             //preProfessOpen Func End
function inputSaveCode(){
    
}

function inputCheatCode(){
    
}

function enterIsland(){
    
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color:black;
 background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:300px 700px; background-position:center top;
}
#game-container{
 width:800px; height:700px;
 border:1px solid white;
 margin:0 auto;
 overflow:hidden;
 padding:0;
}
#warning{
    color:white;
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
}

#start-button{
 width:100px; height:40px;
 position:relative; top:330px; left:350px;
 background-color:red;
 border:1px solid white; border-bottom-width:2px; border-top-width:0px;
 font-size:125%;
 cursor:pointer;
}
#start-button:hover{
 color:white;
}
#logo{
 width:100%; height:300px;
 position:relative;
 z-index:3;
}
#sub-logo{
 text-shadow: 1px 0 5px white, -1px 0 5px white, 0 1px 5px white, 0 -1px 5px white;
 color:#FEFF00;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:50px;
 position:relative; bottom:70px; left:15px;
 z-index:2;
}
#sub-logo-img{
 width:550px; height:405px;
 margin:auto;
 position:relative; left:140px; bottom:170px;
 z-index:1;
}

#main-menu-box{
 width:200px;
 margin:0 auto;
 border:1px solid #444; border-radius:4px;
 position:relative; top:300px;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.main-menu-box-p{
 border-radius:4px;
 background-color:#EEE;
 border:1px solid #666;
 padding-left:20px; padding-top:3px;
 margin:0; margin-bottom:1px;
}

#speech-box{
 width:60%; height:100px;
 background-color:white;
 color:black;
 font-size:125%;
 border:1px solid #999; border-radius:20px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0 10px;
 opacity:.8;
 position:relative; bottom:10px; top:600px;
 cursor:pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout:none;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
  -khtml-user-select:none;
  -moz-user-select:none;
  -ms-user-select:none;
}
.main-menu-box-pic{
 width:20px; height:20px;
 float:right;
 position:relative; bottom:3px;
}

.pointer{cursor:pointer;}
#male{color:#00F; margin-bottom:0;}
#female{color:#F06; margin-top:10px;}
#gender-confirm{
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
#yes-gender-p{
    color:green;
    margin-top:0;
}
#no-gender-p{
    color:red;
}
#name-confirm{
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
#yes-name-p{
    color:green;
    margin-top:0;
}
#no-name-p{
    color:red;
}

#red-on-boat{
    width:10px; height:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <title>Game</title>
 <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
 <meta name="author" content="Some Nerd.">
 <link rel="icon" href="index/src/img/favicon.ico">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index/src/style.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div id="game-container">
  <button id="start-button" onclick="mainMenu()">Start</button>
 </div>
    <p id="warning">Warning: Game cannot be played without Javascript enabled and a browser that supports <span title="Safari 6, Chrome, IE8+, Firefox, Opera 12">HTML5</span>.</p>
 <script src="index/src/src.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would argue that the switch is working correctly. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @will is the issue fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in options 1-6 you are not doing anything except assign some text to variable `speech`. Starting from option 7 you also change value of `speechBox.innerHTML`.

Comment: Glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning text to the variable speech but not doing anything with it.

https://jsfiddle.net/7xzfhm5v/2/

```
switch (speechNum) {
      case 1:
        speechP.innerHTML = "I am Yellow Diamond &ndash; reduced to introducing Pok&eacute;mon Spin-Offs.";
        break;
      case 2:
        speechP.innerHTML = "This world of clods is widely inhabited by creatures known as Pok&eacute;mon.";
        break;
```